# Bash get schema version from command output

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get the cassandra schema version into variable from output of nodetool command.

Here are some of the output of nodetool commands:

```
Cluster Information:
    Name: Test Cluster
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        65e78f0e-e81e-30d8-a631-a65dff93bf82: [127.0.0.1]
```

When few nodes are not reachable here's the output.

```
Cluster Information:
    Name: Production Cluster
       Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
       Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
       Schema versions:
              UNREACHABLE: 1176b7ac-8993-395d-85fd-41b89ef49fbb: [10.202.205.203]
```

Can anyone suggest how to get schema version into variable irrespective of reachable or not?

Tried to use awk and grep commands but didn't work because of unreachable.

Comment: Dp you need the ip too ?

Comment: Just the schema version

Answer (score 1):

Another version of an `awk` script that will match only the UUID type REGEX can be written to use `match()` setting the internal `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` variables that can then be used with `substr()`.

That would be:

```bash
awk '
  /Schema versions:/ {
    set=1
    next
  }
  set {
    match($0,/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}/)
    print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    exit
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '
>   /Schema versions:/ {
>     set=1
>     next
>   }
>   set {
>     match($0,/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}/)
>     print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
>     exit
> }' << 'eof'
> Cluster Information:
>     Name: Test Cluster
>     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
>     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
>     Schema versions:
>         65e78f0e-e81e-30d8-a631-a65dff93bf82: [127.0.0.1]
>
> eof
65e78f0e-e81e-30d8-a631-a65dff93bf82
```

and

```
$ awk '
>   /Schema versions:/ {
>     set=1
>     next
>   }
>   set {
>     match($0,/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}/)
>     print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
>     exit
> }' << 'eof'
> Cluster Information:
>     Name: Production Cluster
>        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
>        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
>        Schema versions:
>               UNREACHABLE: 1176b7ac-8993-395d-85fd-41b89ef49fbb: [10.202.205.203]
> eof
1176b7ac-8993-395d-85fd-41b89ef49fbb
```

You can use the command in a *command substitution* in bash to capture the result in a variable.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Awk will do the job for that:

```bash
version=$(awk '/Schema versions:/ {
  getline
  gsub(/:/,"")
  if ($1 == "UNREACHABLE") {
    print $2
  } else {
    print $1
  }
}' < <(nodetool_cmd)) # remplace "nodetool_cmd" by the correct command

$ echo "$version" #when reachable
65e78f0e-e81e-30d8-a631-a65dff93bf82

$ echo "$version" # when unreachable
1176b7ac-8993-395d-85fd-41b89ef49fbb

# or in single line:

version=$(awk '/version/ {getline;gsub(/:/,"");if ($1 == "UNREACHABLE") {print $2} else {print $1}}' < <(nodetool_cmd))
```